# Change Alt+tab to just tab

Tags: windows-10, alt-tab

I use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> right now, but I'd like to change <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> in <kbd>Tab</kbd>, so I can click <kbd>Tab</kbd> to make the same thing of Tab. How can I make that?

Comment: Just a comment, if you use Alt+Tab a lot, using Alt+Esc might be quicker to go between the two most recent programs. It skips the "program chooser" Alt+Tab shows. Just FYI.

Comment: So, how can I change Alt+Esc to Tab?

Comment: that's a bad idea. Tab is used to move between items on the screen, for example between text boxes, check boxes or buttons. Without it filling a form will be tedious since you'll have to use the mouse to click the next field after entering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a program called SharpKeys that allows you to map any key to any key. That should do in your case.

If you want to do some research yourself, just access the registry at: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout`
You can re-map anything you want there.
The entries are as follows:

00000000 00000000 **02**000000 **3A00E053** 00000000

Here’s how it works:

The first 16 zeros are reserved/unused.
The '02' how many keys you are going to re-map plus 1.
The '3A00' is the key we actually want Windows to map to, which in this example is CAPSL.
The '0E53' is the key we are mapping from, in this case the DELETE key.
The next 8 zeros are EoL marker.

Comment: Is there a easier way? Like a bach script to install that you run when you want it?

Comment: Reg entry modifications can be done via a batch file, so just make 2 of them: one with the modifications and one to undo them.

Comment: Ye, but what is the batch script? I know 0 about that, and I didn't find so much in Google. What's the modifications code?

Comment: Nothing special, just save the reg entry as a .reg file and you can directly run it from a .bat like you would do with an .exe.

Comment: Is the reg 00000000 00000000 02000000 3A00E053 00000000 or HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout?

Comment: To save an entry, open regedit and go to the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout and then using the menu export the content into a .reg (name it original.reg or something); then, make the modifications, and export another file (named altered.reg or anything). You will then be able to use any of the files at any time.

Comment: I'd like to use SharpKeys, but I don't find Alt+Esc or Alt+Tab.